# How to make vertical range slider in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic5

In my app I have to select the height of persons so I want to customize the ionic range slider vertically like in the below image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmwhc.png

Comment: Please add `below image`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Rotate Div Using css:
html

```
<div class="a">
  <ion-item>
   <ion-range min="1000" max="2000" step="100" snaps="true" ticks="false" color="secondary"></ion-range>
  </ion-item>    
</div>
```

css

```
 div.a {
      width: 150px;
      height: 80px;
      background-color: yellow;
      -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
      transform: rotate(270deg);
    }
```

Comment: what about the swipe gesture sir?

Comment: what about it??

Comment: you just changed the direction of UI but the gesture will remain same, Horizontal not Vertical.

Answer (score 0):

try basic html css solution, like what mhartington answered in [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-change-ionic-range-slider-to-vertical-orientation/10414). Or just use angular sliders, like [this one](https://angular-slider.github.io/ngx-slider/).