# How to create a vertical ion-range

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJzHX.gif)Hello i want to create a vertical -not horizontal ion-range in capacitor 4. I followed the instructions here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/range and i created a horizontal one but i want to create a vertical.

```
<ion-range (ionChange)="onIonChange($event)"></ion-range>
<ion-label>ionChange emitted value: {{ lastEmittedValue }}</ion-label>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this link "https://angular-slider.github.io/ngx-slider/demos#vertical-sliders"

Answer (score 0):

ion-range elements are horizontal by default. your code here should result in a horizontal range, if it doesn't, probably some other parts of your code is messing with it. Check out your css files to find the problem.

If you mean vertical ranges, you can see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74346100/14661202).

Comment: Thanks Amir yes i meant vertical, sorry. I used  angular sliders but the pin doesnt stop to move up and down.

Comment: @SimonIoa then check the html css solution. like [this](https://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/KKJaVe)

Comment: I use https://angular-slider.github.io/ngx-slider/demos